# Yum - is it possible to search all remote packages for a specific file?

Tags: centos, yum, package-management, rpm

It frequently happens that I forget which remote packages contain the files necessary for something to install; I want to be able to search them for these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...
yum whatprovides FileName

Comment: Some basic globbing is available, too. e.g.   yum provides "*bin/iostat"